# CSS Background Image limits to content instead of entire page

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

So, I made a gradient image for the background of my site and since it didn't have much detail I figured I would take the image and use background-image and stuff with CSS to stretch it out over the page. However, the image refuses to stretch vertically the correct way. I can get it to stretch horizontally just fine, but no matter what I do, it will not stretch vertically to 100% on the page, and instead it limits itself to the content on the page, which I do not want. The only way I can get the picture to stretch horizontally without dead-setting the pixel length is by using cover, but then it becomes too tall. Can anyone give me a piece of code I can use to expand the image to fit the page horizontally and vertically? Because it refuses to and I don't know why

This is the CSS code I have in my style tags in the head

```
body {  
    background: url('Background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Its hard for us to understand without seeing your code. Post your code mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters background-repeat is set to no-repeat.

You need to make the body fill the browser no matter how much content it contains or it will only repeat as far as the content.

Edit:

Make the page fill the browser winder no matter what the content.

```
html, body { height: 100%;}
```

Comment: I don't want it to repeat at all though, its a single image I want to fill the entire window

Comment: It still refuses to work

EDIT: Oh, I didn't realize the 'html,' part was necessary. Its working now, thanks man

Comment: Still refuses to let me upvote, don't have 15 reputation yet apparently, sorry